# How to remove list item if it doesn't have sub list or list item?

Tags: php, jquery

i'm showing list of elements and also it has sub-elements, so when it doesn't contain any sub-elements then i want to remove list item of element from list.

This is for a new Windows, running MySQL 5, PHP 5 and Apache 2.

```
    <ul>
        <li class="main-list">food
           <ul>
                <li class="sub-list">Chinese</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Italian</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Continental</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-list">Drinks</li>
    </ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //what should i write here to remove list item (li) dynamically from list whenever it doesn't have any sub element. });
```

i want to remove main-list element if it doesn't have sub-list element using jquery.

Comment: In this case you want to remote the 'Drinks' item?

Comment: Please also post the jquery code you are using that isn't working.

Comment: like i want to remove drinks li element because it doesn't have any sub element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do script like this, it will work fine:-

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="main-list">food
           <ul>
                <li class="sub-list">Chinese</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Italian</li>
                <li class="sub-list">Continental</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-list">Drinks</li>
    </ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
   $(".main-list").each(function() {
      if($(this).find('ul').has('li').length == 0){
        $(this).remove();
      }
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me,even if i have blank <ul> inside list item of first unorder list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it whit Jquery like this:

```
$("li.main-list:not(:has(ul))").remove();
```

May you need call it when document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("li.main-list:not(:has(ul))").remove();
});
```

Comment: You could just write `$(() => $("li.main-list:not(:has(ul))").remove());`

Comment: it won't work if i have empty <ul> inside <li> of list